# Simple counter changing the color of counter value in react ja

Tags: html, class, styles

in counter app i want color of counter value should be as (if counter>0- value should be displayed in "green" and counter<0 value should be in "red"

Comment: Can you share the code that you already have?

Comment: i have used classNames package but i need the code without using classNames src.zip (file://DESKTOP-PH4BJ42/Users/user/counter/src.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hooks useEffect for that.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div className={`${(count <= 0) ? "red" : "green"}`}>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I just followed the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) the added a basic ternary operator